# ¿Cómo dibujar en un QWidget secundario dentro del widget principal?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

estoy haciendo un proyecto, lo que quiero saber es como puedo dibujar en un **widget secundario** dentro del Qwidget pricipal. Ya sea para mostrar por ejemplo: circuferencias, fractales, etc.

Comment: Necesitamos mas información para ayudarte, ¿el QWidget principal es una ventana?, y el secundario ¿que objeto es?, cuando te refieres a dibujar te refieres a mostrar una imagen o ¿a hacer anotaciones con el raton?. Aclara la situacion y muestranos tu codigo de pruebas.

Comment: Debes editar tu pregunta y ser más específico. No obstante, en `Qt` todo funciona con con `layouts`, si tienes un `QWidget` padre y quieres agregar un `Qwidget` hijo o cualquier otro componente puedes hacerlo, usa `layouts` para distribuir las proporciones del tamaño del **widget** padre según los estilos que hayas creado en los **widgets** hijos dentro del padre. Puedes ayudarte de la [documentación](https://doc.qt.io), espero que te sea de ayuda.